# When was "in the which" correct English grammatical usage?

Tags: archaicisms

In the King James Version of the Old Testament, the phrase ***in the which*** is used in Genesis 1:29, 42:38, 19:29, 45:6 and Numbers 6:5. It is also used in the New Testament: Luke 19:30, 23:29, John 4:53, 5:28, Acts 17:31, 26:16, Colossians 3:7, and Peter 3:10. For example:

> - If mischief befall him by the way ***in the which*** ye go, then shall ye bring down my gray hairs with sorrow to the grave. (Gen. 42:38 KJV)
> - Go ye into the village over against you; ***in the which*** at your entering ye shall find a colt tied, whereon yet never man sat: loose him, and bring him hither. (Luke 19:30 KJV)

The phrase *in the which* appears to be an archaic use of English that is no longer acceptable grammar. During what time period would this usage have been acceptable grammar?

Comment: Can you include some of these examples in the post?

Comment: Late Middle and early Modern English (1400-1600) probably.

Comment: "The which" appears to be a nominalised adjective, (The OED has it as a pronoun.) 1611  Bible *Doe not they blaspheme that worthy Name, by the which ye are called?* ++ 1660  P. Heylyn *To put his hunting spear amongst them, and the which of them soever should lay hold upon it, should be..drawn out of the water.* 1682  J. Bunyan *He told too, the which I had almost forgot, how Diabolus had put the Town of Mansoul into Arms.* ++ It was continued to indicate religious or archaic language: 1884  Ld. Tennyson *He holp the King to break down our castles, for the which I hate him.*

Comment: It used to be grammatical for articles to modify relative pronouns. Now it's not.

Comment: Interesting. How would we know if it were a relative pronoun or a nominalised adjective? ++ *a1824   Ld. Byron Wks. (1842) 193/1   Finished copying August..1820; the which copying makes ten times the toil of composing. ++ 1861   D. G. Rossetti tr. Dante Vita Nuova in Early Ital. Poets ii. 297   Of the which thing I bethought me to speak unto her.* If the noun is omitted, it still makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

*The which* is indeed archaic and used nowadays to convey an antiquated atmosphere. [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2021/02/the-which.html#:%7E:text=In%20older%20English%2C%20%E2%80%9Cthe%20which,a%20preceding%20sentence%20or%20clause.)'s investigation sheds light on your query:

> In older English, “the which” was sometimes used in place of “which” alone, a ***usage dating from the early 1300s***. Essentially, for a few hundred years “the which” competed with “which” as a relative pronoun and a relative adjective.
>
> Linguists say ***“the which” was common in the early Modern English period (late 1400s to late 1600s) but had fallen out of use by the late 1700s***. Today, the Oxford English Dictionary says, it’s archaic.

For curious minds, the site gives the first instances of the phrase:

> The OED’s earliest uses of “the which” in writing, as both a relative pronoun and a relative adjective, are from Cursor Mundi, an anonymous Middle English poem believed written sometime before 1325. At the time, “the which” was written a variety of ways: “Þe quilk,” þe whilk,” “Þe whiche,” etc.

The article concludes with what I said in the beginning, that its use is limited today and used with the intention to evoke a past period or style of language:

> Uses of “the which” were uncommon after the late 18th century, as we said above, but they occasionally appeared afterward, ***mostly in poetic or historical writing***.